# Android: how to center horizontally a ConstraintLayout inside a ListView row?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to center a `ConstraintLayout` inside a `ListView`'s row (the ListView contains 6 rows, each containing 6 squares).

I have written this inside the view XML:

```
<!-- Grid view -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_view_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_view"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_view" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The row XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:maxWidth="306dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/box1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.166666"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/box2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.166666"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/box1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/box3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.166666"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/box2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/box4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.166666"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/box3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/box5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.166666"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/box4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/box6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.166666"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/box5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

    </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I look at the design version of it in Android Studio, it looks like this:

[image]

So it looks like well centered, but when I compile the app, nothing appears on screen.

If I replace `test_id`'s `layout_width` with `match_parent`, the list view appears but the content is sticked to the left of the screen instead of centered:

[image]

What should I do here?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Specifying constant size for a view is usually wrong. Your layout is not in right format. Please specify what you want to achieve. And try to remove `maxWidth="306dp"` from `test_id` and add these lines to it:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
```